# Adding Bass and Treble control to existing schematic

Tags: amplifier, audio, stereo, portable

I have a little project in mind that I want to try.
This picture below is a stereo amplifier circuit. For more info about it, you can see this page. [Stereo Amp](http://cdselectronics.com/Kits/Stereo%20Amp.htm)

[image: Stereo Amplifier]

The circuit above only has Gain and Volume control, how do I add Bass and Treble control?
Where do I add them?
How's the circuit layout/schematic?

Thank you.

Comment: This device is a power amplifier. Any adjustment to frequency response would normally be done in a preamp stage that feeds this circuit. Where is your input coming from?

Comment: The input is from 3.5mm jack I think. So before this circuit, there is a preamp circuit for frequency adjustment? How's the circuit?

Comment: So, there is a circuit before this one to adjust frequency? How's the circuit?

Comment: I can't recall the name for this more or less standard circuit, but you find it used everwhere: http://www.next.gr/audio/tone-balance-filters/Audio-tone-control-circuit-l7585.html As described on the page itself it is line level, so it is to be connected at the left of your circuit diagram, the low power / pre-amp stage.

Comment: You could insert a Baxandall filter between the coupling C and the variable resistor. It'll work, but a separate preamp stage might be better. Or see if you can increase the amp's gain to compensate for the loss (say 10dB) of the filter.

Comment: Hmmm, good suggestions. I'll try them all, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two circuits you could use:

http://www.diyaudio.com/forums/parts/144872-help-understanding-tone-circuit.html

Whichever you choose, you will need two of them, one for left, and one for right. Connect the output of the tone control circuit above to the input of your amplifier circuit. Use dual pototentiometers so you can have one treble control, and one bass control, each of which will affect both left and right channels simultaneously.

Here are some other bass / treble circuits:

- http://www.electronicecircuits.com/electronic-circuits/bass-treble-tone-control-circuit
- http://www.ampbooks.com/mobile/amp-technology/james-tonestack-synthesis/

Comment: It seems, this is the easiest one to implement. Thanks, @jodes.

Comment: Oh yeah, one more thing. I'm not sure about the components value from bass/treble circuit. Could you help me out?

[Multisim Circuit](http://s1312.photobucket.com/user/dawnmaster/media/Screenshot%2086_zpsw2hwilua.png.html)

Comment: That's a very good question!! I will see if I can find out, or find a different circuit for you...